# why width of &nbsp; is different?

Tags: css, firefox

```
<style>
span {  
font-family: "Fixedsys", "Courier New", Courier, mono, serif;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #E7E5DC;
}
span{word-spacing:-10px}/*FireFox*/
*html span{word-spacing:0}/*ie6fixed*/
*+html span{word-spacing:0}/*ie7fixed*/
</style>
<div>
<span>IE&nbsp;firefox&nbsp;space&nbsp;width</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>IE firefox space width</span>
</div>
```

I run code above in FF and IE, line with &nbsp; shows same width space in IE as line with space. but is another story in FF.
I want code above to show same width of space, &nbsp; and space, in FF, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try tell you browser about monospace with <code tag. Here is my worked sample:

```
<style>
span {  
font-family: "Fixedsys", "Courier New", Courier, mono, serif;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #E7E5DC;
}
</style>
<div>
<code>
<span>IE&nbsp;firefox&nbsp;space&nbsp;width</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>IE firefox space width</span>
</code>
</div>
```

Comment: I find you removed my css lines with word-spacing, why? Plus, In my FF, width of 2nd line space is only half of 1st line with &nbsp;, I hope &nbsp; have narrow width like width of space in 2nd line

Comment: +1 This solution is working for me. I guess the `word-spacing` was removed because it was the property that was causing the words to bunch together in Firefox!